# why do we pass argument in lambda function?

Tags: lambda, arguments

```
print(*(sorted(input(), key=lambda x: (x.isdigit(), x.isdigit() and int(x)%2==0, x.isupper(), x.islower(), x))), sep='')
```

Can any one explain why we pass argument x in lambda when sorting array ?

sort should be in this mannner
Ex = String123
1.lowercase
2.uppercase
3.even
4.odd

Ans : ginrtS132

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] and tag a language ([tag:python]?)

Comment: Also, format your code: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

The `key` argument is a function which will be executed on each one of the members of the input (list, tuple, etc.).
After the `key` function is executed, the sort of the input will be done by comparing the results of the outputs of the `key` function.
That means that the `key` function will have to have an argument, which is one value from the input, therefor the input `x` is defined and used inside the lambda.
Lambda is a lightweight definition of a function, but we still need to tell it which are the arguments it works on.